# How to handle multiple collada scenes?

Tags: webgl, three.js

I want to handle multiple collada files with Three.js in following way:

1. Load and display "01.dae". After a while destroy this scene.
2. After "01.dae" has been destroyed successfully, load and display "02.dae". After a while destroy this scene too.
3. ...

How could I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Have you been able run the example with single collada file?

Comment: Of course. I'm familiar with the Three.js examples and I'm able to open single collada files. However I'm unable to destroy current collada scene and then load a different one on the same cancvas. Could you help me please? I'm using "mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html" for opening collada files. I would like to extend this file to handle multiple collada scenes. However any help or code would be appreciated.